How to use snekmate?
I have installed snekmate for my vyper contracts like so:
pip install snekmate

And I have it in my virtual environment. What's the best way to import it into my Vyper contracts?
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
# @version 0.4.0

number: public(uint256)

@external
def set_number(new_number: uint256):
    self.number = new_number

@external
def increment():
    self.number += 1

Let's say I wanted to install and run ownable.

There is a dedicated section on this: https://github.com/pcaversaccio/snekmate#-usage.
Please check all the mocks and you will understand how to use them.
but essentially you can import all modules via the snekmate namespace: e.g.
# pragma version ~=0.4.0
from ethereum.ercs import IERC20
from ethereum.ercs import IERC20Detailed
from snekmate.auth import ownable
from snekmate.tokens import erc20


initializes: ownable
initializes: erc20[ownable := ownable]
exports: (
    erc20.owner,
    erc20.IERC20,
    erc20.IERC20Detailed,
    erc20.mint,
    erc20.set_minter,
)


@deploy
def __init__():
    ownable.__init__()
    erc20.__init__("Vyper", "VY", 18, "Vyper", "1")

Additional Examples
https://github.com/curvefi/autobribe/tree/main/contracts
More Resources
Ask here: https://github.com/pcaversaccio/snekmate/discussions?discussions_q

The vyper compiler is intelligent enough to look for modules in your python virtual environment.
So, if you ran pip install snekmate you should be able to directly import from the snekmate package.
Here is an example of a minimal ERC20 contract:
# This is how you import the ownable.vy module
from snekmate.auth import ownable as ow
# And this is how you initialize it
initializes: ow

from snekmate.tokens import erc20
# https://docs.vyperlang.org/en/latest/using-modules.html#initializing-a-module-with-dependencies
initializes: erc20[ownable := ow]

@deploy
@payable
def __init__():
    erc20.__init__("my_token", "MT", 18, "my_token_dapp", "0x02")
    ow.__init__()

